# Total hours in Odoo 11

Tags: odoo, odoo-11

How can I get total hours in Odoo 11?

```
start_time = fields.Datetime("Start Time")
end_time = fields.Datetime("End Time")
total_hours = fields.Integer("Total Hours")
```

Thanks.

Comment: Its completely different in odoo-11 you have to pick one odoo version

Answer (score 1):

I achieved this using

```
@api.depends('start_time','end_time')
def get_hours(self):
    seconds = (self.end_time - self.start_time).total_seconds()
    self.total_hours = seconds // 3600

start_time = fields.Datetime("Start Time")
end_time = fields.Datetime("End Time")
total_hours = fields.Integer("Total Hours",compute="get_hours",store=True)
```

and if want minutes also you can try this:

```
@api.depends('start_time','end_time')
def get_hours(self):
    seconds = (self.end_time - self.start_time).total_seconds()
    hours = seconds // 3600
    minutes = (seconds % 3600) // 60
    self.total_hours = '{} hours, {} minutes'.format(hours, minutes)

start_time = fields.Datetime("Start Time")
end_time = fields.Datetime("End Time")
total_hours = fields.Char("Total Hours",compute="get_hours",store=True)
```

Comment: thanks a lot, I will try and give you feedback after.